# Condition on SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

The below SQL query is in a SQL Server 2017. I want when the value of `UtenteCliente.CostoFatturazionePersonalizzato` is 0 or null is configured with the value of `Utente.CostoFatturazione`, to do this I use the query below but the result always returns null.

How can I do this?

SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
    IIF (UtenteCliente.CostoFatturazionePersonalizzato < 0
         OR UtenteCliente.CostoFatturazionePersonalizzato IS NULL, 
         Utente.CostoFatturazione, UtenteCliente.CostoFatturazionePersonalizzato) AS costo
FROM 
    Utente
INNER JOIN 
    UtenteCliente ON Utente.IdUtente = UtenteCliente.IdUtente
WHERE 
    Utente.IdUtente = 2
    AND UtenteCliente.IdCliente = 6
```

Comment: UtenteCliente.CostoFatturazionePersonalizzato is 0 and in your condition UtenteCliente.CostoFatturazionePersonalizzato < 0 ??

Comment: Can you put some sample data and expected output in your question by editing it?

Comment: Switch to a `case` expression instead of that iif. `case when UtenteCliente.CostoFatturazionePersonalizzato <> 0 then UtenteCliente.CostoFatturazionePersonalizzato else Utente.CostoFatturazione end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expression instead `IIF()`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ISNULL(UtenteCliente.CostoFatturazionePersonalizzato, 0) = 0
             THEN Utente.CostoFatturazione
             ELSE UtenteCliente.CostoFatturazionePersonalizzato
        END) AS costo
FROM Utente INNER JOIN 
     UtenteCliente 
     ON Utente.IdUtente = UtenteCliente.IdUtente
WHERE Utente.IdUtente = 2 AND 
      UtenteCliente.IdCliente = 6;
```